# Undirected graph is a Bipartite graph

Tags: graph

How can I write a code to Decide if a given undirected graph is a Bipartite graph (Time Complexity - Linear time )? I am not getting any idea, a little help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To check if a graph is bipartite, you can check if it is [2-colorable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring#Vertex_coloring) (it is equivalent).

A solution to this problem can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477648/how-to-tell-if-a-graph-is-bipartite). I've copied the main steps below in case the link stopss working.

1. Colour any one of your vertices red.
2. Identify all uncoloured vertices that are adjacent to a red vertex. Colour them blue.
3. Identify all uncoloured vertices that are adjacent to a blue vertex. Colour them red.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 until all the vertices are coloured red or blue.
5. If there are any two vertices adjacent of the same colour, then your graph is not bipartite, otherwise it is bipartite.
6. If the graph is bipartite, the colouring algorithm will have created the two required sets of points (one red and one blue).

This algorithm is not optimal, since it does not run in linear time. You can have a linear time algorithm (`O(E)` with `E` the number of edges in the graph) by coloring greedily the vertices of your graph in a [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or a BFS.